# Aggregate duplicate records by maintaining the order and also include duplicate records

Tags: scala, list, time-complexity, aggregate-functions

I am trying to solve an interesting problem, it's easy to just do a groupBy for aggregation like sum, count etc. But this problem is slightly different. Let me explain:

This is my list of tuples:

```
val repeatSmokers: List[(String, String, String, String, String, String)] =
  List(
    ("ID76182", "sachin", "kita MR.", "56308", "1990", "300"),
    ("ID76182", "KOUN", "Jana MR.", "56714", "1990", "100"),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", "255"),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", "110"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "20"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "6750"),
    ("ID76182", "DOWNES", "RYAN", "47542", "1990", "2090"),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", "200"),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", "280"),
    ("ID76182", "JAMES", "JIM", "30548", "1990", "300"),
    ("ID76182", "KIMMELSHUE", "RUTH", "55345", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", "370"),
    ("ID76182", "COOPER", "ANADA", "45873", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", "256")
  )
```

The schema for these records are `(Idnumber, name, test_code, year, amount)`. From these elements, I want only repeated records, the way we define unique combination in the above list is by taking `(sachin, kita MR.,56308)` name and test_code combination. Which means if the same name and test_code is repeating it's a repeat smoker record. For simplicity you can assume only test_code as unique value, if it repeats you can say it's a repeat smoker record.

> below is the exact output:

```
ID76182,27539,1990,255,1 
ID76182,27539,1990,365,2
ID76182,45873,1990,20,1 
ID76182,45873,1990,6770,2 
ID76182,45873,1990,9370,3
ID76182,49337,1990,200,1
ID76182,49337,1990,570,2
ID76182,47542,1990,280,1
ID76182,47542,1990,536,2
```

Finally, the challenging part here is to maintain the order and aggregate sum on every second repeat smoker record and also add occurences.

For example: this record schema is: ID76182,47542,1990,536,2

IDNumber,test_code,year,amount,occurences

since it occured twice we see 2 above.

> Note:

output can be a list are any collection but it should be in the same format I mentioned above

Comment: What would be the exact final output?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is some code in Scala but it is really a Java code just written in Scala:

```scala
import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.LinkedHashMap
import scala.collection.convert._


type RawRecord = (String, String, String, String, String, String)
type Record = (String, String, String, String, Int, Int)
type RecordKey = (String, String, String, String)
type Output = (String, String, String, String, Int, Int, Int)
val keyF: Record => RecordKey = r => (r._1, r._2, r._3, r._4)
val repeatSmokersRaw: List[RawRecord] =
  List(
    ("ID76182", "sachin", "kita MR.", "56308", "1990", "300"),
    ("ID76182", "KOUN", "Jana MR.", "56714", "1990", "100"),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", "255"),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", "110"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "20"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "6750"),
    ("ID76182", "DOWNES", "RYAN", "47542", "1990", "2090"),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", "200"),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", "280"),
    ("ID76182", "JAMES", "JIM", "30548", "1990", "300"),
    ("ID76182", "KIMMELSHUE", "RUTH", "55345", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", "370"),
    ("ID76182", "COOPER", "ANADA", "45873", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", "256")
  )
val repeatSmokers = repeatSmokersRaw.map(r => (r._1, r._2, r._3, r._4, r._5.toInt, r._6.toInt))

val acc = new LinkedHashMap[RecordKey, (util.ArrayList[Output], Int, Int)]
repeatSmokers.foreach(r => {
  val key = keyF(r)
  var cur = acc.get(key)
  if (cur == null) {
    cur = (new ArrayList[Output](), 0, 0)
  }
  val nextCnt = cur._2 + 1
  val sum = cur._3 + r._6
  val output = (r._1, r._2, r._3, r._4, r._5, sum, nextCnt)
  cur._1.add(output)
  acc.put(key, (cur._1, nextCnt, sum))
})
val result = acc.values().asScala.filter(p => p._2 > 1).flatMap(p => p._1.asScala)
// or if you are clever you can merge filter and flatMap as
// val result = acc.values().asScala.flatMap(p => if (p._1.size > 1) p._1.asScala else Nil)

println(result.mkString("\n"))
```

It prints

> (ID76182,GANGS,SKILL,27539,1990,255,1)
>   
> (ID76182,GANGS,SKILL,27539,1990,365,2)
>   
> (ID76182,SEMI,GAUTAM A MR.,45873,1990,20,1)
>   
> (ID76182,SEMI,GAUTAM A MR.,45873,1990,6770,2)
>   
> (ID76182,SEMI,GAUTAM A MR.,45873,1990,9370,3)
>   
> (ID76182,DRAGON,WARS,49337,1990,200,1)
>   
> (ID76182,DRAGON,WARS,49337,1990,570,2)
>   
> (ID76182,HULK,PAIN MR.,47542,1990,280,1)
>   
> (ID76182,HULK,PAIN MR.,47542,1990,536,2)

The main trick in this code is to use Java's [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as the accumulator collection because it preserves the order of insertion. Additional trick is to to store some lists inside (as I use Java-collections anyway I decided to use `ArrayList` for the inner accumulator but you can use anything you like). So the idea is to build a map of key => list of smokers and additionally for each key store current counter and current sum so "aggregated" smokers can be added to the list. When the map is built, go through it to filter out those keys that have not accumulated at least 2 records and then convert a map of lists to a single list (and this is the point where it is important that `LinkedHashMap` is used because insertion order is preserved during iteration)

Comment: I am hoping that we can still optimize this solution. I will wait for few more days, and will accept this answer if there are no additions here. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordon, accepting an answer is always up to the OP. Still I'd like to know what characteristic do you want to optimize? Do you want it to perform better? Be more idiomatic Scala? Something else? After some point you can't optimize all the characteristics so you have to decide which is really important to you (and sacrifice what is less important).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functional way of solving this problem:

For this input:

```
val repeatSmokers: List[(String, String, String, String, String, String)] =
  List(
    ("ID76182", "sachin", "kita MR.", "56308", "1990", "300"),
    ("ID76182", "KOUN", "Jana MR.", "56714", "1990", "100"),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", "255"),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", "110"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "20"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "6750"),
    ("ID76182", "DOWNES", "RYAN", "47542", "1990", "2090"),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", "200"),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", "280"),
    ("ID76182", "JAMES", "JIM", "30548", "1990", "300"),
    ("ID76182", "KIMMELSHUE", "RUTH", "55345", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", "370"),
    ("ID76182", "COOPER", "ANADA", "45873", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", "2600"),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", "256")
  )
```

With an case class representing the record:

```
case class Record(
    id: String,
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
    code: String,
    year: String,
    amount: String)
```

We can run the following:

```
val result = repeatSmokers
  .map(recordTuple => Record.tupled(recordTuple))
  .zipWithIndex
  .groupBy { case (record, order) => (record.fname, record.lname, record.code) }
  .flatMap {

    case (_, List(singleRecord)) => Nil // get rid of non-repeat records

    case (key, records) => {

      val firstKeyIdx = records.head._2

      val amounts = records.map {
        case (record, order) => record.amount.toInt
      }.foldLeft(List[Int]()) {
        case (Nil, addAmount) => List(addAmount)
        case (previousAmounts :+ lastAmount, addAmount) =>
          previousAmounts :+ lastAmount :+ (lastAmount + addAmount)
      }

      records
        .zip(amounts)
        .zipWithIndex
        .map {
          case (((rec, order), amount), idx) =>
            val serializedRecord =
              List(rec.id, rec.code, rec.year, amount, idx + 1)
            (serializedRecord.mkString(","), (firstKeyIdx, idx))
        }
    }
  }
  .toList
  .sortBy { case (serializedRecord, finalOrder) => finalOrder }
  .map { case (serializedRecord, finalOrder) => serializedRecord }
```

This produces:

```
ID76182,27539,1990,255,1
ID76182,27539,1990,365,2
ID76182,45873,1990,20,1
ID76182,45873,1990,6770,2
ID76182,45873,1990,9370,3
ID76182,49337,1990,200,1
ID76182,49337,1990,570,2
ID76182,47542,1990,280,1
ID76182,47542,1990,536,2
```

Some explanation:

A pretty nice way to instantiate a case class from a tuple (creates a List of Records from the list of tuples):

```
.map(recordTuple => Record.tupled(recordTuple))
```

Each record is tupled with its global index (Record, index) in order to be able to have a way to latter work with orderings:

```
.zipWithIndex
```

We then group using the key you required:

```
.groupBy { case (record, order) => (record.fname, record.lname, record.code) }
```

Then for each key/value resulting from the group stage, we will output a list of records (or an empty list if the value is a single record). Thus the flatMap which flattens the lists which will be produced.

Here is the part getting rid of single records:

```
case (_, List(singleRecord)) => Nil
```

The other case deals with the creation of cumulative amounts (this is a List of Int) (note for Spark developers: groupBy does preserve the order of value elements within a given key):

```
val amounts = records.map {
    case (record, order) => record.amount.toInt
  }.foldLeft(List[Int]()) {
    case (Nil, addAmount) => List(addAmount)
    case (previousAmounts :+ lastAmount, addAmount) =>
      previousAmounts :+ lastAmount :+ (lastAmount + addAmount)
  }
```

These amounts are zipped back to records in order to modify each record amount with the given accumulated amount. And it's also there that records are serialized to the final desired format:

```
records
    .zip(amounts)
    .zipWithIndex
    .map {
      case (((rec, order), amount), idx) =>
        val serializedRecord =
          List(rec.id, rec.code, rec.year, amount, idx + 1).mkString(
            ",")
        (serializedRecord, (firstKeyIdx, idx))
    }
```

The previous part also zipped records with their index. In fact each serialized record is provided with a tuple (firstKeyIdx, idx) which is used to then order each record as needed (first per order of apparition of the key (firstKeyIdx) and then for records coming from the same key, the "nested" order is defined by idx):

```
.sortBy { case (serializedRecord, finalOrder) => finalOrder }
```

Comment: "_Here is a functional way of solving this problem_" and as it often is with functional solutions I suspect much less performant. I think `sortBy` alone having `O(N*log(N))` complexity is worse than my whole solution on a relatively big datasets. Obviously, for small datasets it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional/recursive way of solving this problem, based on @SergGr's solution which rightfully introduced the LinkedHashMap.

Given this input:

```
val repeatSmokers: List[(String, String, String, String, String, Int)] =
  List(
    ("ID76182", "sachin", "kita MR.", "56308", "1990", 300),
    ("ID76182", "KOUN", "Jana MR.", "56714", "1990", 100),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", 255),
    ("ID76182", "GANGS", "SKILL", "27539", "1990", 110),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", 20),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", 6750),
    ("ID76182", "DOWNES", "RYAN", "47542", "1990", 2090),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", 200),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", 280),
    ("ID76182", "JAMES", "JIM", "30548", "1990", 300),
    ("ID76182", "KIMMELSHUE", "RUTH", "55345", "1990", 2600),
    ("ID76182", "DRAGON", "WARS", "49337", "1990", 370),
    ("ID76182", "COOPER", "ANADA", "45873", "1990", 2600),
    ("ID76182", "SEMI", "GAUTAM A MR.", "45873", "1990", 2600),
    ("ID76182", "HULK", "PAIN MR.", "47542", "1990", 256)
  )
```

By first preparing and aggregating data this way:

```
case class Record(
  id: String, fname: String, lname: String,
  code: String, year: String, var amount: Int
)

case class Key(fname: String, lname: String, code: String)

val preparedRecords: List[(Key, Record)] = repeatSmokers.map {
  case recordTuple @ (_, fname, lname, code, _, _) =>
    (Key(fname, lname, code), Record.tupled(recordTuple))
}
```

.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

def aggregateDuplicatesWithOrder(
    remainingRecords: List[(Key, Record)],
    processedRecords: LinkedHashMap[Key, List[Record]]
): LinkedHashMap[Key, List[Record]] =
  remainingRecords match {

    case (key, record) :: newRemainingRecords => {

      processedRecords.get(key) match {
        case Some(recordList :+ lastRecord) => {
          record.amount = record.amount + lastRecord.amount
          processedRecords.update(key, recordList :+ lastRecord :+ record)
        }
        case None => processedRecords(key) = List(record)
      }

      aggregateDuplicatesWithOrder(newRemainingRecords, processedRecords)
    }

    case Nil => processedRecords
  }

val result = aggregateDuplicatesWithOrder(
  preparedRecords, LinkedHashMap[Key, List[Record]]()
).values.flatMap {
  case _ :: Nil => Nil
  case records =>
    records.zipWithIndex.map { case (rec, idx) =>
      List(rec.id, rec.code, rec.year, rec.amount, idx + 1).mkString(",")
    }
}
```

Comment: And this time your `aggregateDuplicatesWithOrder` is effectively `foldLeft` that you for some reason decided to write yourself from scratch. And this is quite close to my code. Actually I was considering using `foldLeft` instead of `forEach` but decided that since I use mutable data structure anyway, it makes no sense. Also I suspect that adding to the end of the Scala `List` is performs worse than Java `ArrayList` that I use exactly for this reason. The thing I like here is using `flatMap` to filter. And I stole this into my solution.