# Improve both time and space complexity for reading a .txt file in Scala with schema details

Tags: java, scala, time-complexity, filereader, space-complexity

I have written code for reading a file which is working fine but when I try to load a bigger file, let's say 500MB file, it's giving memory issue's.

I tried to increase heap size, and clear all the GC etc but keeping all that a side, can we write a better code for reading a file in Scala?

Can we think of using a better data structure than Array or List which can do things more efficiently for us?

This is my file:

```
JuaNetalisa629618|Neta|GED|P|56017012333513|24|CaNetaada|79365678403|LOS ANetaGELES|CA|90017|PRINetaCIPAL|heya|01032017|40|H6CA34245|SA01251735122|1141239|||201252017136899850783
JuaNetalisa177436|Neta|MetaDeta|P|78017020390894|75|CaNetaada|79365678403|ALPHARETTA|GA|300047357|ghkjef|tyue|01312017|384||JU3845050|1147350||PareNetatiNetag|402082017870029337
JuaNetalisa384818|Neta|MetaDeta|P|6802039042412|15|CaNetaada|79365678403|WOONetaSOCKET|RI|028956146|CVS HEALTH|iejnfe|01122017|250||2017020211435-887|1147467|||402890171370030285
JuaNetalisa384516|Neta|MetaDeta|P|56702039042410876|85|CaNetaada|79365678403|LOOKOUT MOUNetaTAINeta|GA|028956146|ghkjef|sega|01312017|230||JU895345050|1147350||PareNetatiNetar|4020789171370029335
JuaNetalisa177436|Neta|MetaDeta|P|201702039042410895|115|CaNetaada|79365678403|LOOKOUT MOUNetaTAINeta|GA|307502818|ghkjef|jona|10312017|384||JU2283905245050|1147350||PareNetatiNetag|4020820178970029342
```

There are five records here all starting with this prefix `JuaNetalisa`. And this is my code for reading the file:

**First case class:**

```
case class DosaTable(Dosa_ID: String,YHDT: String,ETEN: String,DATASCIENCE: String,PNG: String,TYPE: String,ETYPE: String,NAAM: String,SHAHAR: String,PATA: String,PATA_CODE: String,DUKAN: String,KAAM: String,TARIK: String,PAISA: String,BAKI: String,PATANAAM: String,KATA: String,KAUN: String,KALA: String,SANJI: String)
```

**Read function:**

```
def readFile (path: String): List[String] = {
  val bufferedSource = scala.io.Source.fromFile (filename)
  val lines = (for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines () ) yield line).toList
  bufferedSource.close
  lines
}
```

**Loading file with schema-case class:**

```
val fileLines = readFile ("filePath")

  val requiredTable = fileLines.map {
  record =>
  val column = record.split ("\\|")
  DosaTable (columns (0), columns (1), columns (2), columns (3), columns (4), columns (5), columns (6), columns (7), columns (8), columns (9), columns (10), columns (11), columns (12), columns (13), columns (14), columns (15), columns (16), columns (17), columns (18), columns (19), columns (20) )
}
```

**The final goal is to select only few columns:**

```
val requiredColumns = requiredTable.map (x => (x.Dosa_ID, x.PATA_CODE, x.DUKAN, x.KAAM, x.TARIK, x.PAISA) )
```

Hope it's all clear, right now, it's taking more than 30 minutes to load schema details of a file with 160 MB size, with records more than 1 million. I need to improve this a lot!!

Comment: Just don't read all lines into a `List` at once. Read lines only when required instead. You can use `bufferedSource.getLines` itself. Why eagerly read all lines from this Iterator ?

Comment: Can you explain more, how can I not read records at once? I need to read all the records to perform a computation. I cannot compute on whole dataset without loading into some data structure?

Comment: Not all computations require eager loading. Similarly not all computations can be done with reading only when required. If your computation is such that you "need" to eagerly load the whole dataset than you need to increase JVM memory.

Comment: You haven't demonstrated why you need to read the entire file into memory. In fact, your "final goal" contains only 6 of the original 21 columns of data from each record. If that's the case then there's lots of data you don't need to keep at all and can be discarded before reading the next record from the file.

Comment: @jwvh the goal is after all cleaning/polishing the data, I need to groupBy PATA_CODE, DUKAN and perform aggregations like sum etc on whole dataset

Comment: You might need to read the whole file into memory, but so far you haven't made a convincing argument for it. Most forms of aggregation, like `grouped`, `sum`, etc., can be done on an `Iterator`. There's a reason `getLines` returns an `Iterator[String]`, it's very memory efficient.

Comment: thanks @jwvh just to explain more about what actually going to do, this answer contains the details. After all cleaning/polishing the data, I am going to similar operations which are in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782282/aggregate-duplicate-records-by-maintaining-the-order-and-also-include-duplicate

Comment: "can we write a better code for reading a file in Scala?" - you probably won't be able to write anything that's much better than Postgres for that type of problem. I mean, it already has all the B-trees and indices and optimized SQL queries, and it knows how to read through a lot of data on disk without running out of memory. What's the point of reinventing a wheel, especially such a complex one?

Comment: thanks @AndreyTyukin for your comment. I want to implement this only using pure scala/java way without uses any computation engine or databases like postgres etc